# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.mule.tools:maven-mule-plugin:1.5:attach-test-resources

Tags: maven, mule, m2e, gnip

I'm getting this error: **"Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.mule.tools:maven-mule-plugin:1.5:attach-test-resources (execution: default-attach-test-resources, phase: validate)"**

I'm using MuleStudio 1.30 and I'm trying to run the mule example that is included in gnip4j.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

p.s. I'm a total maven n00b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix it by adding the following xml snippet section to your pom.xml **build**

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.mule.tools
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-mule-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.5,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>
                                            attach-test-resources
                                        </goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

You can find more information on the topic [here:](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered)